# Ruby on Rails: Rendering element tags with html options if attribute is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes, rendering

I am trying to render a label with an html attribute `data-color` but only if an object attribute is available.

This is what I have, but it's not rendering the label which I assume is because it's saying the attribute isn't available so don't show the label, not the attribute:

```rb
f.label :value, choice.label, class: 'fs-button', data_color: choice.color if choice.attribute_present? :color
```

How would I properly set the html attribute `data-color` if the object attribute is present? The `data-color` attribute shouldn't show up at all if the attribute is not present.

Comment: Then the hash needs to be constructed on the basis of the attribute's presence, or you need to re-code to use a non-existent value as well.

Comment: Why I didn't think of that is beyond me, my brain is fried. Thank you!